# Como faço para realizar um setTimeout após um outro setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Eu tenho o seguinte código dentro do meu script:

(function() {
'use strict';

```
let $leftside_div = document.querySelector('.leftside-div');
let $centerside_div = document.querySelector('.centerside-div');
let $rightside_div = document.querySelector('.rightside-div');

$leftside_div.addEventListener('click', handleIncorrectAnswer, false);
$centerside_div.addEventListener('click', handleCorrectAnswer, false);
$rightside_div.addEventListener('click', handleIncorrectAnswer2, false);

const redirectToCorrectPage = () => {
window.location.href = "right-answer.html";
```

}

const redirectToIncorrectPage = () => {
window.location.href = "wrong-answer.html";
}

```
function handleCorrectAnswer() {
    $centerside_div.classList.replace('centerside-div', 'centerside-div-js' );
    $rightside_div.classList.replace('rightside-div', 'rightside-div-js-no-display');
    $leftside_div.classList.replace('leftside-div', 'leftside-div-js-no-display');
    setTimeout(redirectToCorrectPage, 1000);
}


function handleIncorrectAnswer() {
    $centerside_div.classList.replace('centerside-div', 'centerside-div-js' );
    $rightside_div.classList.replace('rightside-div', 'rightside-div-js-no-display');
    $leftside_div.classList.replace('leftside-div', 'leftside-div-js-no-display');
    setTimeout(redirectToIncorrectPage, 2000);
}

function handleIncorrectAnswer2() {
    $centerside_div.classList.replace('centerside-div', 'centerside-div-js' );
    $rightside_div.classList.replace('rightside-div', 'rightside-div-js-no-display');
    $leftside_div.classList.replace('leftside-div', 'leftside-div-js-no-display');
    setTimeout(redirectToIncorrectPage, 2000);
}
```

})()

Existem 3 setTimeout sendo executados, no qual o da função handleCorrectAnswer está levando para uma página específica, e as funções handleIncorrectAnswer e handleIncorrectAnswer2 estão levando para uma outra única página.

Eu já tentei colocar o script na página de redirecionamento, porém, como existem duas páginas de redirecionamento, eu não consegui criar a lógica de como ela iria voltar para a página que eu desejo que ela voltasse.

A minha dificuldade que estou encontrando é o seguinte: Eu gostaria de, após realizar um setTimeout e entrar na outra página, esperar e realizar outro Timeout para redirecionar para outra página, tudo na mesma função. Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: se você está mudando de paginas... ao mudar de página seu contexto js é perdido, oque você pode fazer é tentar sinalizar pela url com alguma string padrão depois de # ou ?, para não afetar o local de destino, ou ainda por cookies, e na página de destino, pegar oque está na url depois de # ou ?, ou no cookie, para verificar, e aplicar o proximo setTimeout se for o caso...

Comment: ah menos é claro que você esteja usando a API history, que não parece ser o caso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve guardar a informação da pagina anterior em um LocalStorage.

**Guardando valor:**

```
let key = 'item 1';
localStorage.setItem(key, 'value');
```

**Recuperando valor**

```
let myItem = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Dessa maneira você consegue ter um fluxo entre as paginas com esse valor guardado na memoria do seu navegador.

Comment: Ah, okay. Muito obrigado!